# android alarmmanager + task schedule

Tags: android, task, alarmmanager

I need help. Im new to android coding.

I have made task list, which I want to do specific things at time written in task.

Here is my task item

```
private long id;
private int mon;
private int tues;
private int wednes;
private int thurs;
private int fri;
private int satur;
private int sun;
private int profile;
```

Where I have days (monday,tuesday etc) which holds amount of minutes (for 10:00 its 600).

Following some tutorials I have alarm reciever

```
public class AlarmReciever extends  BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("profile", message);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Its still unedited...

And then there is code which calls to make new tasks in alarm manager

```
// get a Calendar object with current time


Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
 Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
 intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "O'Doyle Rules!");
 // In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 // Get the AlarmManager service
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

I dont understand how to specify in calendar, that I need new task repeating (for example) every monday at 10:00, and that when this happens, it calls new function, giving it "profile" variable to work with.

```
 private void setProfile(Integer profile)
{
 // Doing things with profile
}
```

Comment: Hi, you need ask specific problem here on SO. Like I did this and this and I run the code and I got this error so My Question is this.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the following code:

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, SampleAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Set the alarm's trigger time to item hour
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, NuevoItemActivity.hora.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, NuevoItemActivity.hora.getCurrentMinute());

    // Set the alarm to fire , according to the device's clock, and to repeat once a day.
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, (PendingIntent) alarmIntent);
```

As you can see in last line, you are able to indicate `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` to repeat the `PendingIntent`.